# How to connect generic smartphone LCD screen to take HDMI input from e.g. laptop?

Tags: lcd, display, hdmi

For a certain project that has a specific screen size requirement, I want to use a phone-sized screen (6") to take HDMI from a laptop. Here is an example product:

https://www.amazon.ca/Digitizer-Display-Tactile-Compatible-Samsung/dp/B07P5CWXFB/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=6+inch+lcd+screen&qid=1589071330&sr=8-6

However it's pretty bare bones, and so I'm not sure how I could output a computer's video onto it via HDMI (or similar means). I don't understand the electronics needed to make this work.

What connectors/parts/modifications/whatever would make a display like the above be able to display the screen of my laptop?

Comment: start with a pocket-sized HDMI screen, or connect the screen to a compatible interface, not HDMI.

Comment: I want to use the specific screen I linked.

Comment: how badly do you want that?  most cases of "you can't get there from here" can be solved if you are willing to spend enough money or effort.

Comment: Phone screens use an interface such as MIPI-CSI or LPDP. They are not compatible with HDMI. I have done it with a purchased $1000 bridge but not something that s easy to do.

Comment: And notice that you have linked to an Amazon catalog page instead of a manufacturer's datasheet do you won't have the technical details you need or any technical support.

Comment: Consider running a webserver app built using www.gnoga.com or any other webserver (on the laptop) to serve up the content you want, then connecting to it from a browser app on a phone or tablet.